# "Vacation days" or "days off"

Tags: differences, expressions

What is the right expression: *vacation days* or *days off*?

Comment: They're both fine, as are *holidays* and *leave*. In some jobs you'll also have *rest days*.

Comment: This might also be a good question for this area51 proposal: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30887/professional-matters?referrer=t0qzW5ESkS-JS6wd42Y-3w2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both expressions are grammatically correct. They mean slightly different things, however.

*Vacation days* generally refers to paid vacation, which are days for which you are paid to work, but don't actually come in. In most organizations, vacation days are usable at the employee's discretion, up to a certain yearly limit.

*Days off* is a more informal phrase that includes a variety of kinds of paid-not-to-work days, including sick leave, maternal/paternal leave, floating holidays, national holidays, etc. *Vacation days* are a subset of *days off*.

Comment: I submit that "vacation days" is not a subset of "days off", because "days off" can also refer to *unpaid* time, in jobs that don't offer vacation days.  Contrast this with "vacation" which is almost always paid.

Comment: @John: It really depends on the particular job, or at least industry. For example, if your job isn't Monday–Friday by default (for example, hospital workers), then your *days off* might be the one or two days a week that correspond to other people's weekend. If you're on a salary, then these aren't strictly speaking *unpaid*, but they're not vacation, either.

Comment: @Martha: True, but this is more evidence against it being called a subset.

Comment: Well, there's no doubt that *vacation days* is a subset of *days off*, where *days off* is what is listed in the answer shown.  If you broaden the definition of *days off*, you will still be including *vacation days* as a subset.  The only way *vacation days* isn't a subset of *days off* is if you deny the answer shown, and replace it with the notion that *days off* can *only* refer to unpaid time, or *only* refer to weekend or analogous.

Comment: @JohnGietzen "Day Off": you are not at work. "Vacation Day": you are not at work AND being paid. Sounds like a subset to me.